# Accessing member function from member variable of different C++ class

Tags: c++

I got into the scenario where I need to call member function from member variable of different class.

Example:

```
class B {
  void foo() {
    // Need to call bar()
  }
};

class A {
  B b;
  void abc() {
    b.foo();
  }
  void bar() {}
};
```

I need to call bar() method from foo(). One way of doing is passing this to foo() function, but that I think is inefficient way of doing it.

Please suggest any efficient ways of doing it. I am interested to learn how people follow different approach to solve this.

Comment: Well, for one, `B.foo();` should be `b.foo();`. Apart from that, somehow the instance of `A` on which you're calling `abc()` needs to make it's presence known to `foo`, somehow. Not going to sugarcoat it: the code smell of this design is raging-pungent, so maybe think about it some more.

Comment: Sorry it was mistake from my side. It is infact `b.foo()`. I wanted to learn the design choice people make that's why I posted the question.

Comment: To call a function on an object, you *need* an instance of said object to invoke it on (unless it is `static`).

Answer (score 0):

Is there another way to solve your problem without doing that? Because even if you manage to do this, it would be a bad coding practice.

But if there's not another way, it's a little better to make foo() a static method. So you can call it by B::foo()

Answer (score 0):

There generally exist two different kinds of functions.

One kind, that's static member functions, global functions, or global functions in a namespace. They **do not** reference or otherwise depend on members of a class instance. You can call these from one or another class, no problem.

The other kind is the (non-static) member function. It **does** in some way reference, access, change, use, or otherwise depend on *something* that is a class member. If you want to call such a function, you need the `this` pointer.
When calling a function from "inside" the class itself, then `this` is implicit. So, if you type e.g. `bar()` inside `A::abc`, then that's really `this->bar()`, only without you needing to type that.
From "outside", that is e.g. in `B::foo`, you will need to supply an object, or else the compiler has no way of knowing what data to operate on. It does not, and cannot work without.

So, you need to decide whether whatever happens in `bar` depends on members of `A` or not. If it does, you have no choice. Passing an object pointer (reference) is not about being inefficient, it's about *"possible or not possible"*.

Otherwise, if there is maybe only some common functionality that is used by both `B::foo` and `A::bar`, in which case you could move that functionality to a (namespaced) global function or a non-capturing lambda, or anything the like.
You could thus for example call `detail::blah()` from *both* `B::foo` and `A::bar` without needing to pass an object. That way, you would not need to duplicate code.

Or well, make `A::bar` static, which will also work but in my opinion has no advantage, and is less clear (as it somehow makes the function a part of `A`, logically, when in reality that's not truly the case).